Image is not updating from Pinia
My store and state is updating correctly. I'm using Ionic with vue.js composition with Pinia.
When I make a selection on a previous route to select a new image the image is updated correctly in pinia, but the image is not reactive in the next route. It comes back as undefined even though pinia is updated I just get a blank image. The image paths are correct, I just can't get reactivity.
How Can I get reactivity for images that change in the store using vue.js composition?
the else statement is true console.warn('Image data is undefined or missing name.');
Code
<template>
    <ion-page>
        <mm-header pageTitle="Select Color">
            <template v-slot:select-button>
                <a href="#" @click.prevent="selectAndSave">Select</a>
            </template>
        </mm-header>
        <ion-content :fullscreen="true">
            <div :class="`bg-${themeColor}-500 h-full`">
                <img :src="mmImage" alt="Image" v-if="mmImage" class="w-full" />
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-page>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
import { onIonViewDidEnter } from '@ionic/vue';
import { useMantraStore } from '@/stores/MantraStore';
import { IonPage, IonContent } from '@ionic/vue';
const router = useRouter();
const mantraStore = useMantraStore();
const themeColor = computed(() => mantraStore.myMantra.color);

const mmImage = ref('');

onIonViewDidEnter(() => {
    console.log('Home page did enter');
    if (mantraStore.myMantra.image && mantraStore.myMantra.image.name) {
        console.log('Image name:', mantraStore.myMantra.image.name);
        mmImage.value = new URL(`/src/assets/images/mantra-images/portrait/${mantraStore.myMantra.image.name}`, import.meta.url).href;
        console.log('Image path:', mmImage.value);
    } else {
        console.warn('Image data is undefined or missing name.');
    }
});

const selectAndSave = () => {
    router.push('/select/photo');
};
</script>

Data
state: () => ({ 
    myImage: {
        color:'yellow',
        image:{
            id:0,
            name:'0-1440x3200.gif',
            alt:'Happy faces'
        }
    }
}),


Can you add the code from where you are updating the value in the pinia store?

Reactivity means recalculating values when dependencies change.
You only set mmValue in onIonViewDidEnter, which only be called once. So the ref value won't change when onIonViewDidEnter is fired.
This will work:
import { computed } from 'vue'

const mmImage = computed(() => {
  if (mantraStore.myMantra.image && mantraStore.myMantra.image.name) {
    console.log('Image name:', mantraStore.myMantra.image.name);
    const result = new URL(`/src/assets/images/mantra-images/portrait/${mantraStore.myMantra.image.name}`, import.meta.url).href;
    console.log('Image path:', result);
    return result
  } else {
    console.warn('Image data is undefined or missing name.');
  }
})

computed will execute the function and collect dependencies, then re-execute the function when dependencies change.
